# How to extract Guid from URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

EDIT:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
 {
      ..........
 }

 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Edit(decimal? balance)
 {
      .......
 }
```

I'm trying to extract GUID from a URL.

I have a Index page and when the user click on `EDIT` (GET) its add `GUID` to the `action name` in this case will be `EDIT`

So my URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:55097/Admin/Edit/a2cc5900-bdff-41f1-9c2a-21032a5275de
```

Once the user is on Edit page (POST) and try to submit the changes then I need to know what what `GUID` is:

What I want to achieve is to just get the `GUID`  or `/Edit/{guid}`

Tried couple of Request but none of it works for me and if I tried this `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` it gives the full url which i do not want.

Comment: Does the model you are editing have a property for the GUID? What is the signature of your GET and POST methods?

Comment: Why are you posting back just a decimal instead of your model? Inspect the html your generating for the form tag (if your using `@using(Html.BeginForm())` the `action` value should have `yourController/Edit/a2cc5900-bdf.....` in which case you could just change the POST method to `public ActionResult Edit(decimal? balance, Guid id)`

Comment: I am not posting entire page just one field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why haven't you included `Guid id` as a parameter of your post method?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, decimal? balance)
```